# Add custom field to the Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using [Tempus Dominus Date/Time Picker v4.17.47](https://github.com/Eonasdan/tempus-dominus) and I need to add a custom field to the time picker. It should contain selected time + some more time to show the estimated time of finished work. Like this way:

[image]

Is there any ability to do such customization?